# Can a CSV in a text variable be COPY-ied in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

For example, say I've got the output of:

```
SELECT
$text$col1, col2, col3
0,my-value,text
7,value2,string
0,also a value,fort
$text$;
```

Would it be possible to populate a table directly from it with the COPY command?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You would have to strip the first two and last lines of your example in order to use the data with `COPY`. You could do this by using the `PROGRAM` keyword:

```
COPY table_name FROM PROGRAM 'sed -e ''1,2d;$d'' inputfile';
```

Which is direct in that you are doing everything from the `COPY` command and indirect in that you are setting up an outside program to filter your input.

Comment: Super close, but this Postgres instance is running on Windows. I tried using: 

PROGRAM 'echo $d' inputfile;

But that doesn't quite seem right either. I think my batch scripting and string parameters are screwy.

Comment: How do you get your output to appear on the command line? Know also that there are Windows command line implementations of `sed`.

Comment: I wasn't getting it to appear on the command line originally. Was only formatting some default data as a csv, then putting that in the $text$ tags, all in plpgsql. I was hoping to be able to use that format to copy while keeping the csv format inside of my sql script.

Comment: Must the solution be `copy`, then? Seems like it would be a lot easier just to insert the raw data from the source to the destination, without formatting, via plpgsql. Are you looking for a more general csv input solution?

Comment: It does not necessarily have to use the copy command. It is only for purpose of easy human reading that having the csv written very literally inside of sql script is preferred (specifically so that some users who are not technically proficient with sql, but do recognize csv could make edits to tables they recognize as their own input).